# How to toggle 2 classes with ECMAScript

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have two CSS classes. One that fades in an element's opacity `class-A` (using CSS3 Keyframes). And the other that fades out the opacity back to 0 `class-B` (using CSS3 Keyframes).  Is there a way in pure ecmascript to toggle between these two classes?  On first click, `class-A` loads.  If you click it again, `Class-B` loads.  If you click it a third time `class-A` loads, etc...

The following is the extent of my knowledge on toggling classes, relating to click event handling....

```js
 var anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
 for (var i = 0, len = anchors.length; i < len; i++) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (this.classList.contains('my-trigger')) {
         document.querySelector('.what-i-am-fading-in-and-fading-out-on-clicks').classList.toggle('class-A');
      }
    }
 };
```

It's easy to fade in an element when I click on my link `my-trigger` the first time.  But my end goal is to have a nice fade out process on the element, when my link is clicked a 2nd time, or 4th time, etc...How can I capitalize on this?

Comment: The last thing you wrote confused me, do you want a transition between opacity 0 and 1, or do you want to press the button multiple times before toggling the class?

Comment: Sorry for any confusion.  I want to depend on each click to transition an opacity.  On click, if the opacity is currently 0, then it should go to 1 (class-A). If the opacity is 1, then it should go to 0 (class-B).  I'm sure there are many ways to do this. my mind for some reason is just not registering more options.

Comment: Ok i think i maybe got what youre searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if i understand it right, but you could add an if statement to look if the opacity is 0 or 1, and then add the classes, once a class is added you dont need to look for it.

You can change the opacity of #test to 1 or 0 and it will change respectivley to it.

```js
let test = document.getElementById("test");
let but = document.getElementById("but");

but.onclick = ()=>{
    if(test.classList.contains("a")||test.classList.contains("b")){
        test.classList.toggle("a");
        test.classList.toggle("b"); 
    }else{
        
        if(window.getComputedStyle(test).getPropertyValue("opacity") == "0"){
          test.classList.add("b")
        }else{
          test.classList.add("a")
        }
        
    }

}
```

```css
#test{
    width:100px;
    height:25px;
    background:black;
    opacity:1;
}

#but{
    width:50px;
    background: lightgrey;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.a{
    opacity:0 !important;
    transition:opacity 300ms;
}

.b{
    opacity:1 !important;
    transition:opacity 300ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Grocery Bud</title>
    <!-- font-awesome -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <!-- styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div id="but">Button</div>
</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example.  This is the first time I'm actually learning about getComputedStyle, through your example.  Much appreciated,  Your end result is exactly what I'm looking for.  Testing it in my code offline now...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the easiest way to toggle the class with Animation using ES6 **(classList.toggle)**

```js
let toggleElement = document.getElementById("toggleElement");
let but = document.getElementById("btn"); 
but.onclick = ()=>{ 
   toggleElement.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
 

#toggleElement{
    width:150px;
    height:25px;
    background:Red;
    opacity:1; 
    padding:10px;
}
 
.ele{
    opacity:0 !important;
    transition:opacity 300ms;
}

.ele.active{
    opacity:1 !important;
    transition:opacity 300ms;
}
```

```html
 
 <button id="btn">Button</button>
 <div id="toggleElement" class="ele" > Toggle CSS Class </div>
```